# Parsing JSON Data with Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion

I'm using the Gaug.es API to track some simple stats, and I'm trying to incorporate this data into my backend.  The API returns data in JSON format, and despite my best efforts, I always seem to struggle with this format.  Indeed, some years ago I asked a JSON-related question here and the answer to that has formed the starting point for this - but my old, rusty brain doesn't seem to be able to get my head around this one!

Here's what I have so far;

```
<cfhttp url="https://secure.gaug.es/gauges" method="GET" resolveurl="YES">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-Gauges-Token" value="myAPIKey">
</cfhttp>

<cfset gaugeResult = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.filecontent)>

<cfdump var="#gaugeResult#">

<cfset formattedData = [] />
<cfset tmp = {} />

<cfloop collection=#gaugeResult# item="gauges">
<cfset tmp.title = gaugeResult[title] />
<cfset tmp.todayviews = gaugeResult[today]["views"] />
<cfset arrayAppend(formattedData,duplicate(tmp)) />
</cfloop>

<cfdump var=#formattedData# />
```

A screenshot of the gaugeResult cfdump is attached.

[image]

Essentially what I need to do is grab the id, title, today>views and today>people figures, which I'll then add to a database.

The current query returns an error "Variable TITLE is undefined" - and my limited understanding in this area has left me somewhat baffled!

Comment: The title exists in an array, so you'll want to loop over the array.  For instance, to get the first title it will probably be gaugeResult.gauges[1].title

Comment: @JedihomerTownend thanks, you are indeed correct.  Amending my code to this; 

    <cfloop collection=#gaugeResult# item="gauges">
    <cfset tmp.title = gaugeResult.gauges[1].title />
    <cfset tmp.todayviews = gaugeResult.gauges[1].today["views"] />
    <cfset arrayAppend(formattedData,duplicate(tmp)) />
    </cfloop>

And it returns correctly.  However, it only returns the first 'result' (presumably because of the [1].  If I remove [1], it throws an error again.  How can I get it to return all results, without having to specifically reference the rows individually (the number will vary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question, then something like this should do the trick. The data you want is in an array so just loop over the array.

```
<cfset formattedData = []>
<cfloop array="#gaugeResult.gauges#" index="it">
   <cfset arrayAppend(formattedData, {
       id = it.id,
       title = it.title,
       todayViews = it.today.views,
       todayPeople = it.today.people
   })>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#formattedData#">
```